# Strange Laravel Error (Join from scope) Bad ID col

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel-4, eloquent

Here is the error output

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is 
ambiguous 
(SQL: update `table1` inner join `table2` on 
`table1`.`type_id` = `table2`.`id` set `type_id` = 2, 
`updated_at` = 2015-01-09 19:36:16 
where `table1`.`site_id` = 1 and `id` = 1)
```

In this I only edited the table names for purposes of asking this question. The query in question is setting the "type" of an item in a table, table1 has the id and it relates to table2's definition of the type (name, desc, ect).

This is the raw error output and however there is a bad ID at the very end, it should be `table1.id` not just `id`. Not only that but the join should not even be in the update.

Normally this would be a fast and easy fix but its all strictly `Eloquent`. The only strange part is I am using a scope to apply the join, I believe that is what is causing this, however digging though the docs I haven't seen a way to fix it yet.

My scope is applied from the following:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder)
{
    $builder->join('table2', 'table1.type_id', '=', 'table2.id');
}
```

I am thinking I need to wrap it in some sort of if statement, but the docs have been a dead end, none of the examples use such a thing.

Anyone got any ideas of a way to fix this? Gonna dive into the source code but that is always a dull experience.

EDIT: here is the query more or less from Eloquent

```
$model = Model::find($id); 
$model->type_id = 2; 
$model->save();
```

EDIT:

A promising idea was to manually set the primaryKey of the model to `table1.id`, however doing that caused it to use `table1.table1.id` instead. Seeing that I tried to just set `id` but it led back to the original issue of not adding `table1`.

Comment: Can we see the code that actually executes "the query in question"?

Comment: literately just `$model = Model::find($id); $model->type_id = 2; $model->save();` I will add it to the question though.

Comment: Is the primary key of your model `site_id` or `id`?

Comment: ID, site_id comes from another scope to filter all records by sub domain, there is no issues with that one.

Comment: I think the problem is that normally you don't do joins when updating so Laravel doesn't bother to use the fully qualified column name. As a workaround you could try adding `protected $primaryKey = 'table1.id';` to your model

Comment: Does changing `$model = Model::find($id);` to `$model = Model::where("id", "=", $id)->first();` change anything? I'm curious if the lack of a closure - `get() or first()` - on `::find()` has any effect, or it `find()` has a built in closure.

Comment: Well I use the same code for many models and it has no issues, so I doubt that (tried, no change), also on the primarykey idea it seemed promising but fixed the original issue! so it became `table1.table1.id`, putting just `id` made it just `id` though lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override these on your model:

```
// if you have timestamps on both tables
const UPDATED_AT = 'table1.updated_at';
const CREATED_AT = 'table1.created_at';

protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query)
{
    $query->where($this->getQualifiedKeyName(), '=', $this->getKeyForSaveQuery());

    return $query;
}
```

And you'll be good!

Comment: I knew it would be such a simple fix :D Thank you! Seems to work, however the `UPDATED_AT` and `CREATED_AT` constants should not be prefixed and left alone, does not work with them but works without them.

Comment: @JordanRamstad constants should be changed as well if you have timestamps on both joined tables, otherwise situation will be the same as with the `id`. If that's not the case you can skip this part.

Comment: When I changed it as you had shown there, it led to it going `table2.table1.created_at` for the joined tables, so it seems that at least for those it is correctly adding the table to the column.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it will be hard to find exactly where it is, seems to be due to a join with a permissions table from Sentinel. Not the same problem or even the same call, but adding that to the model causes it. The original issue has no connection with Sentinel though so adding those constants just created another issue (though works fine without).

Comment: OK I see. So hopefully you don't need that and there's no need to further adjust basic `Eloquent` features.